# Doesn't Uncertainty Principle disproves the whole Quantum Physics's measurements?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Let's say Heisenberg was right that we can't measure both location and velocity of a small particle at the same time, So doesn't it say that the observations of any experiment that we have done in all these years wasn't actually the exact outcome of those phenomenons?

And because we formulated and explained everything based on our observations (done both by man and machine), So how can we be sure that every calculation we've done is accurate and accountable and explains those phenomenons?

Note: Actually this principle even disproves itself too, Because Heisenberg himself couldn't be sure that he did understand this Uncertainty Principle for that he also was limited by ordinary observation techniques.

Comment: So where does that leave us? No offence, but I don't follow your argument that the uncertainty principle stops a position being measured to the limits of our current measurement accuracy (or a velocity), just not at the same time.

Comment: Physical theories only have one function: to describe the behavior of nature. Quantum mechanics does that with up to 12 digits of precision. I think that's pretty good for a failed theory. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne oh, I have a feeling there are alternative theories around, here and there....

Comment: @AcidJazz: There is a whiff of that in the air, indeed... :-)

Comment: Sorry for the rant: Why do people keep getting this idea that they can disprove 100 years of scientific progress with five minutes of thought? Are they so arrogant that they really believe they're the first ones to even think of such simple issues?

Comment: @Javier: When you don't know enough about a subject you just don't know what you don't know. Few people have the self-discipline not to make a fool of themselves under these circumstances. In the US, for instance, there must be approx. 25 million people who know exactly how to coach an NFL team... and the NFL knows that in any given year there are only a couple... the guy who coached the winning team and the guy who coached the runner-up.

Comment: Even worse, nobody has *ever* come up with a way of determining the particle's favorite movie.  Given that, how can we trust anything in physics?

Comment: I love the "done both by man and machine", clearly added for extra thoroughness! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't measure location and velocity at the same time because they require different equipment to have exclusive access to the object.

But that isn't what the uncertainty principle is about, not in the slightest. Take sound. You can make sounds that have a really precise pitch, or sounds that happen for a very short duration. But when you choose to make a sound there is a tradeoff at some point being really brief makes a spread of pitches. And making a good pitch requires an long duration. This has nothing to do with quantum mechanics its just the way waves are.

The same things happens with light. You can make a very short pulse but it has a range of colors, or you can make something with a very very narrow range of colors but then it can't be a short pulse it has to be a long pulse. Again, this is just how waves work.

When we discovered that matter is determined by waves all the limitations of waves turned out to apply. So back when you choose to make your matter wave you can make one out of a narrow range of velocities (colors, pitches) but it will have a spread of locations (durations, pulse length). Or you can make one that is confined to a small region (short duration, short pulse width) and it will (if small enough) require a large range of velocities (pitches, colors).

That is what happens when you have waves in nature. The waves can have a nice wavelength (pitch, color, velocity) or a tight spread (duration, width, location). And the tradeoff happens regardless whether it is a sound wave (pitch and duration) a light wave (color and width) or a matter wave (velocity and location).

Make sure to get mad at light and sound if waves bother you so much.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say Heisenberg was right that we can't measure both location and
>   velocity of a small particle at the same time, So doesn't it say that
>   the observations of any experiment that we have done in all these
>   years wasn't actually the exact outcome of those phenomenons?

Outcome of what observation to what degree of precision?

> And because we formulated and explained everything based on our
>   observations (done both by man and machine), So how can we be sure
>   that every calculation we've done is accurate and accountable and
>   explains those phenomenons?

Because when we use the calculations to produce an expected outcome, we achieve the expected outcome.  If we didn't achieve the expected outcome we would have to explain why.  Do you really think that we got from here to the moon on dumb luck and random values?

> Note: Actually this principle even disproves itself too, Because
>   Heisenberg himself couldn't be sure that he did understand this
>   Uncertainty Principle for that he also was limited by ordinary
>   observation techniques.

Not: You committed the fallacy of ambiguity.  Heisenberg could be quite sure he understood the uncertainty principle because it is reproducible.  You are confusing the uncertainty principle with the observer effect.